# Recursive function to get sequence not working correctly

Tags: c, function, if-statement, recursion, ansi-c

I am trying to program a sequence x(n) in C with the following conditions:

```
    x(0)=x
    x(n)=1 if x(n-1)=1
    x(n)=3*x(n-1)+1 if x(n-1)!=1 and x(n-1) not even
    x(n)=x(n-1)/2 if x(n-1) even
```

I tried the following:

```
  int sequence(int x, int n){

    if(n==0){
     return x;
    }


    if (sequence(x,n-1)==1){
     return 1;
    }

   if((sequence(x,n-1)!=1)&&((sequence(x,n-1)%2)!=0)){

      return 3*sequence(x,n-1)+1;

    }

    if((sequence(x,n-1)%2)==0){
     return sequence(x,n-1)/2;
    }


  }
```

It should give me the n-th element of the sequence with the starting point x. However, it does not work...

Comment: "Does not work" is not as specific as required. Use your debugger to provide more details.

Comment: It is compiling but I am not getting the results I want.

Comment: Yes, that's basically the definition of "does not work".

Comment: Well, to what details are you refering?

Comment: The condition `x(0)=x` doesn't appear to make sense.  Is `x` a value or a function?

Comment: It is the initial value.

Comment: Explain the expected value.

Comment: For instance the initial value 3 should have the sequence 3,10,5,16,8,4,2,1,1...

Comment: I tested this code and I got the same sequence for 3.  Please update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code does what you proposed it to do. Maybe your original logic is flawed.

```
f(x,0)=x
f(x,n)=1            if f(x,n-1)=1
f(x,n)=3*f(x,n-1)+1 if f(x,n-1)!=1 and f(x,n-1) not even
f(x,n)=f(x,n-1)/2   otherwise
```

You can clean up your code somewhat to improve its readability and make it slightly faster/better.

```
int sequence(int x, int n){
  if(n==0){
    return x;
  }

  if (sequence(x,n-1)==1){
    return 1;
  }

  if((sequence(x,n-1)%2)!=0){
    return 3*sequence(x,n-1)+1;
  }

  return sequence(x,n-1)/2;
}
```

Comment: It seems to work like this, but what is wrong with my code? If I enter sequence(3,8) I will get 1. Also it seems that I am always getting 1...

Comment: The only difference I can see is the edge case, where you previously required `x(n-1) even` to return a value, and now it happens by default. Like I said, that is based on your logic, not the code itself.

Comment: I found the mistake... The problem was not in the function itself, but I did use scanf() wrong... Thank you anyway.